# Mapbox download offline map from background (service)

Tags: android, maps, mapbox

I want to download Mapbox offline map from background (service). I am following [this](https://www.mapbox.com/android-sdk/examples/offline-manager/) documentation to download offline maps. Sample is working fine.

I tried the same code from Service, and there I don't have "MapView" and "MapboxMap"UI element. Because this is a service.

But I got this exception (and app crashed):

```
Thread[1,tid=19900,Native,Thread*=0xb808e9f8,peer=0x731d7f98,"main"] recursive attempt to load library "/data/app/app package-2/lib/arm/libmapbox-gl.so"
Thread[1,tid=19900,Native,Thread*=0xb808e9f8,peer=0x731d7f98,"main"] recursive attempt to load library "/data/app/app package-2/lib/arm/libmapbox-gl.so"
W/com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.http.HTTPRequest: [HTTP] Request could not be executed: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String okhttp3.HttpUrl.host()' on a null object reference
A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 20752 ()
```

I am using: `com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:4.1.1@aar` version.

So I want to know: is it possible to download offline map from background (service)?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to download a region in a Service. Please  file a bug report on https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues and tag me so that we can look at it.